# Counting Tables rows is producing the wrong answer with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that I allow the user to add rows to. when i load the page it has one row on show and a template row that is hidden.

I want to be able to check the number of rows in the table to prevent the user from removing all the rows.

my table is defined as

```
<table id="tarrifItems">

  <th>Item</th>
  <th>Cost</th>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="item[]" name="item[]"></td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">£</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control money" id="cost" name="cost[]" value="0.00"/>
        </div>
      </td>

      <td>
        <span href="" class="label label-success" onclick="addRow()">+</span>
        <span href="" class="label label-success" onclick="removeRow(this)">-</span>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr id="tarrifTemplate" style="display: none">
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="item[]" name="item[]"></td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">£</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control money" id="cost" name="cost[]" value="0.00"/>
        </div>
      </td>

      <td>
        <span href="" class="label label-success" onclick="addRow()">+</span>
        <span href="" class="label label-success" onclick="removeRow(this)">-</span>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>


</table>
```

This gives a count of 2 rows but when i run the command

```
alert($('#tarrifItems >tbody >tr').length)
```

I have included a fiddle showing this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgUjn/)
it gives me a count of 3. Can anyone suggest where i am going wrong?

EDITED: updated FIDDLE Link to correct fiddle

Comment: Do you have duplicate IDs for table in page??also put correct fiddle link.

Comment: The extra `th` before `tbody` produce an extra row. Check it out: http://jsbin.com/kexuk/1/edit

Comment: Great, Thanks for that. So do I just adjust my counting to allow for the headings or is there a way to just count the actual rows?

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work at all. It calls jQuery, but doesn't have the jQuery framework loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra th before tbody produce an extra row. Check it out: http://jsbin.com/kexuk/1/edit

And counting `tr` will also include the rows with `display: none`, because they still exist in the DOM

Suggestion: Wrap the `th` elements in an explicit `thead` element, so that your selector won't  grab them any more

```
<thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Item</th>
   <th>Cost</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `th` be inside `tr`?

Comment: I had used `thead` inside the `tr` which caused the incorrect row count. Now, its fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The `th` tag creates a new `tr` tag. So the count is coming as 3. Put the `th` tag inside the `thead` tag. Then you will get the correct count. Check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JA327/1/)

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML code - there are two header cell `th` exist in code. So the second `th` produce an extra row before tbody.

So, you should put the `th` tag inside the `thead` tag.

```
 <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Item</th>
       <th>Cost</th>
     </tr>   
 </thead>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xY9Ab/)

Note: A table may have **only one header** according [the HTML4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.1).

Comment: Two `th` will produce only one header

Answer (score 0):

alert showing 3 because it also counting one hidden row and heading row.

```
$('#tarrifItems tbody tr:visible').size();
```

i'hv updated you html and js in fiddle

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgUjn/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the nicest way to do it is to set a specific class to the row you add.

```
var clone = $('#tarrifTemplate').clone();
clone.removeAttr('id');
clone.removeAttr( 'style' );
clone.addClass('addedRow') // add a class to the clone 
clone.appendTo('#tarrifItems');
```

And to count it when needed :

```
alert($('#tarrifItems .addedRow').length); // should give you the exact number of rows you added.
```

Answer (score 0):

Some time row count seems to be wrong this because 
Improper taging ie begin and end tag should be 
Proper when dynamically adding rows should be careful